# appending to a list copies the last item python

Tags: python

I am trying to use a path finding algorithm and I want it to print all the steps one by one, this is a simplified code with only the important parts. For some reason this prints out 7 same levels that are only the final step, but I need it to print out all of the steps. The problem seems to be in the appending part, but I don't know how to fix it.

```py
level = [
    [">","#"," "," "],
    [" ","#","#"," "],
    [" "," ","#"," "],
    ["#"," "," "," "],
]

cycle = [[0,0],[1,0],[2,1],[3,2],[3,3],[2,3],[1,3],[0,2]]
output = []
for i in range(len(cycle)-1):
    level[cycle[i  ][0]][cycle[i  ][1]] = " "
    level[cycle[i+1][0]][cycle[i+1][1]] = ">"
    output.append(level)

for i in output:
    for ii in i:
        print(ii)
    print()
```

I need someone to solve this problem for me, as anything on this site doesn't work in my exact problem

Comment: you `append` `level` which is a reference to the same object so all your elements are the same. You need to `append` a copy of the list and because it is nested, you probably want to do a [`deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import copy

level = [
    [">","#"," "," "],
    [" ","#","#"," "],
    [" "," ","#"," "],
    ["#"," "," "," "],
]

cycle = [[0,0],[1,0],[2,1],[3,2],[3,3],[2,3],[1,3],[0,2]]
output = []
for i in range(len(cycle)-1):
    level_copy = copy.deepcopy(level)  
    level_copy[cycle[i  ][0]][cycle[i  ][1]] = " "
    level_copy[cycle[i+1][0]][cycle[i+1][1]] = ">"
    output.append(level_copy)

for i in output:
    for ii in i:
        print(ii)
    print()
```

When you do `level[cycle[i  ][0]][cycle[i  ][1]] = " "` inside the loop, you are referring to the same level object defined in the first line. So you do end up putting level multiple times, but they all are referring to the same object and hence contain the value that was written in the last iteration of loop.

```
level = []
output = []
for i in range (2):
  if i == 0:
    level.append(1) 
    level.append(2)
  else
    level.append(24)
    level.append(25)
  output.append(level)

i = 0: Start: level=[], end: level=[1,2]
i = 1: Start: level=[1,2] end: level=[1,2,24,25] // Observe that it starts with state left at end of first iteration as we are still referring to the same object in memory referred to by variable level.
```

Comment: could it work like
```py
level_copy = level
```
instead of
```py
level_copy = copy.deepcopy(level)  
```
if not, why?

Comment: But in your solution you lose the continuaty. Meaning, you always copy the original list. But the flow is iterative where each iteration alters the last state. Therefore, it would be simply enough to change the original code to be `output.append(copy.deepcopy(level))`. This way you change the original `level` list and each iteration `append` a "snapshot"

Comment: @Sadru no it won't work with `level_copy=level` as then they are just 2 variable names referring to same memory. When you do a deepcopy, you are copying the values from one memory location to another and assigning this new variable to point to that new memory location.